# Podman Container Created Status

Tags: status, podman

I'm having a problem with Podman containers. After logging out of my session they get the status `created`.

The user that I run the Podman commands are created by another user who has sudo privileges. I am logging to the newly created user directly from SSH. I am not changing user after I login to another account.  I am running the containers with `podman-compose`. After a while, **usually after I exit my SSH session**, the containers stop working. When I re-login to my server and check the output of `podman ps -a` command, I see that the container status are `created`. The containers are web application and they stop working.

Steps to re-produce:

- Install `podman`, `podman-compose`.
- Create a user, set their password.
- SSH into the new user directly with new session.
- Run some containers with podman (for example nginx).
- Exit the user session. After a while (~5-10 minutes), the nginx container will stop working.
- SSH into the server again.
- Check the containers with `podman ps -a`. You will see that the status is "created"

Comment: `podman loginctl enable-linger` is what you want to google for. Otherwise systemd cleans up user sessions shortly after you logout.